# Open Activity with Linkify Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-xml

i want to open Activity when users click on textView with linkify...
Heres my code:

```
Pattern tagMatcher = Pattern.Compile("#([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)");

            //Scheme for Linkify, when a word matched tagMatcher pattern,
            //that word is appended to this URL and used as content URI
            String newActivityURL = "content://Solution.Project.WelcomeActivity";
            //Attach Linkify to TextView
            wrapper.Text.Text = post.PostText;
            Linkify.AddLinks(wrapper.Text, tagMatcher, newActivityURL);
```

and my Android `manifest.xml`

```
 <application android:icon="@drawable/Icon" android:label="Welcome">
    <activity android:name=".WelcomeActivity" android:label="@string/WelcomeText">
        <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 </application>
```

And when users click on ***textView***, it throws following exception :

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://Solution.Project.welcomeactivity (has extras) }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intent filter should look like below:

```
   <intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_title_viewgizmos">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.example.com/gizmos” -->
    <data android:scheme="content"
          android:host="Solution.Project.WelcomeActivity" />

</intent-filter>
```

You are missing **data** tag as shown below

**scheme** could be http or your own customized one.

**host** is the link eg xyz.com

**pathPrefix** is optional like /homepage

```
 <data android:scheme="content"
          android:host="Solution.Project.WelcomeActivity" />
```

Read [android Documentation for Deep Linking](https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `provider` tag in your activity with matching `authority`

Comment: [Read this doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html)