# Android: Detect and Open external links in custom web view

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, webview

I am facing a strange problem after putting all the effort I am still unable to solve it.
The problem is:
I have a textview which is loading data directly from `Twitter`. Tweets may contains many links and it is getting displayed in the textview, but on clicking links, they are opening in `android default browser`. What I want to do is when user click any of the link `how will I detect which link has been clicked` and `open my webview instead of default browser`.

Here what I have reached until now:

```
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello www.google.com Thank You"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_textview"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Java

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_textview);
textView.setText("www.google.com is first link, www.facebook.com is second link, www.instagram.com is third link");
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25629691/open-activity-with-linkify-android?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android TextView with Clickable Links: how to capture clicks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12418279/android-textview-with-clickable-links-how-to-capture-clicks)

Answer (score 0):

In the Android manifest inside the activity tag where the WebView reside add:

```
<activity android:name=".WebViewActivity">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http"
        android:host="*" />

</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

On the TextView I did:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/link"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="http://www.google.com"
    android:autoLink="web"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

This worked for me.